# Typeerror str object not callable when normal input()

Tags: python

I'm getting the error after I just added an input ("") and it just broke
It breaks at
input = input("sussy ")

And I can't get it working
It just breaks if I retype it

Code:

````
   
   print("hello to the test")
   sleep(2)
   print("u have to guess the word")
   sleep(2)
   print("lets start")
   sleep(2)
   input = input("alo")
   sleep(0.5)
   if input == "ha":
       print("yes")
       sleep(0.5)
       print("u correct")
       sleep(0.9)
   else:
       print("no")
       sleep(0.6)
       wrongword = "alo" + input
       print("u said", wrongword)
       sleep(0.5)
       print("correct was aloha")
       sleep(0.9)
   print("next word")
   sleep(0.5)
   input = input("sussy ")
   sleep(0.5)
   if input == "baka":
       print("yes")
       sleep(0.5)
       print("u r correct again")
   else:
       print("no")
       sleep(0.6)
       wrongword = "sussy " + input
       print("u said", wrongword)
       sleep(0.5)
       print("correct was sussy baka") ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `input` as a variable name(`input = input("alo")`).
Don't do that. `input` is a predefined in python and you are overriding its main functionality by doing this action... so your second `input()` call will raise an error.
change that line to:

```
my_input = input("alo")
my_input = input("sussy ")
```

then

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `input` as your variable name because it is a reserved keyword, so whenever you say `input =` you are actually ***redefining/changing what future input commands do*** the next time you use them in your code.

For example, if I say `input = print`.  I just *changed* the input command into the print command !

To solve your problem call your input variable something like `text`

e.g. `text = input("alo")`